# Array lengths different using strlen and full array not printing?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to copy a string `plaintext` into another string `ciphertext` in C so that they have the same length and array characters. I cannot seem to get the strings' lengths or content to match. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

I have tried to use `strlen` when initializing `ciphertext` to be of the same size as `plaintext`, and then copy each character of `plaintext` into `ciphertext` and print both strings as well as their lengths.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool is_number(int input);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //checking that user provides only one input argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //check that user key input is an integer
    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(argv[1]); i < l; i++)
    {
        if(is_number(argv[1][i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //prompts user for message
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext:  ");
    char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
    printf("length p: %lu\n", strlen(plaintext));
    printf("length c: %lu\n", strlen(ciphertext));   
    for (int i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
        //printf("p[i] = %c\n", plaintext[i]);
        //printf("c[i] = %c\n", ciphertext[i]);
        //printf("i= %i\n", i);
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);    
}

//checks if a char is a number
bool is_number(int input)
{
    if(input < '0' || input > '9')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, my string lengths do not match and `ciphertext` does not print all of its characters or prints random extra characters.

command line example:

```
$ make caesar
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    caesar.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o caesar
$ ./caesar 1
plaintext:  hello
length p: 5
length c: 6
ciphertext: hell
```

Comment: BTW, good use of enabling many warnings.  Consider `-pedantic`

Answer (score 3):

*Undefined behavior* (UB)

`printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);` attempts to print `ciphertext` assuming it is a *string* (sequence of characters including and ending with a *null character*) which it is not.

`strlen(ciphertext)` requires a *string*.

In C, recall a *string* **must** contain a *null character*, else it is not a *string*.  Many `str...()` functions require a *string*.

---

Code could attempt

```
printf("ciphertext: %.*s\n", (int) strlen(plaintext), ciphertext);
```

to print an array of characters up to a *null character* or to the length or *string* `plaintext`.

`strlen(ciphertext)` is just wrong as `ciphertext` lacks a *null character*.

---

Or consider

```
char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1];  // 1 more 
size_t i;
for (i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];  // ciphertext is not yet a _string_.
}
ciphertext[i] = '\0'; // Now ciphertext is a _string_.
```

---

Also note:

`printf("length p: %lu\n", strlen(plaintext));` is amiss as `strlen()` returns a `size_t` , not necessarily an `unsigned long`.

Use a matching specifier and type.

```
// printf("length p: %lu\n", strlen(plaintext));
printf("length p: %zu\n", strlen(plaintext));
```

---

Tip: the 2 below are functionally equivalent, the 2nd is idiomatic in C.

```
for (int i = 0, l = strlen(argv[1]); i < l; i++)
for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
// of better
for (size_t i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
```

`